How to convert insta360 .insp format to equirectangular format compatible with photosphere viewers?
I've been playing with an insta360 X3 camera.  It produces .insp format JPEG files containing two round views, side-by-side, from the two image sensors.  The file size is 5952x2976 pixels.  Does anyone know what that projection format is called?  Anyway, what I'd like to do is convert those images to equirectangular 8704x4352 similar to what is produced by the Android camera's stitched .PHOTOSPHERE.jpg format.  Then I can use google photos and the photosphere javascript from photo-sphere-viewer.js.org to view them in a way compatible with all my other photospheres.  Any pointers to projection remapping software would be appreciated.  Failing that, I might be able to write my own with a pointer to a description of the mathematics of the insta projection.

photosphere viewer 5.8.0 recently added support for dual-fisheye source images https://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/guide/adapters/dual-fisheye.html#example I've got that working with insta360 .insp images.  There's a significant seam between the two images and scaling the sub-images up by 5.5% and cropping them lessens the seam, but to really stitch the seam to invisibility will require some subtle feature matching and warping.

I worked with images from a Xiaomi Mi Sphere camera, and they were 'dual fisheyes' - two fisheye images, each with slightly larger than 180 degrees field of view, next to each other. I strongly suspect that your images are similar to that. Such images can be converted using panotools-based software like hugin - you need to go through a few steps to get the result:

create a PTO with twice the same image from the camera, projection fisheye
the images need to be horizontally shifted in opposite directions
and masked with a circular lens crop, one fitting the left and one the right image

Then you search for control points, optimize and stitch to full equirect output. Once you have a working PTO, you should be able to reuse it for other images from the same camera, so you only have to go through the creation of the PTO file once - like a calibration. Care to share a test image? Then I can give it a shot.
You may be interested in this thread on hugin-ptx which has a concrete PTO for the Mi Sphere.
